# mongoid has_many children not saving through nested_attributes when Tire::Callbacks included

Tags: mongoid, nested-attributes, tire

So here is the issue:

context:

- mongoid (2.2.6)
- tire (0.5.1)

classes:

```
class Account
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :comments, auto_save: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Tire::Callbacks
  include Tire::Search
  belongs_to :account
end
```

operations:

```
account = Account.first
account.comments_attributes = [{content: 'super'}]
account.comments => [#<Comment content: 'super'>]
```

issue:

```
Comment.count => 0
Comment.search().count => 1
account.comments.build {content: 'super'}
account.save => true
Comment.count => 1
```

it seems that there is conflict with the autosave with nested_attributes change on mongoid and the callbacks of tire ...

Comment: Please add the relevant portions of your mapping definition, and and output or link to output of your model's JSON serialization (Account#to_indexed_json).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was linked to this one => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860594/issue-with-sti-nested-attributes-mongoid-3-0-22

Now it seems to be solved.